# What fallacy is it to say someone is wrong because they believe [some word defined as being wrong]?

Tags: logic, fallacies, argumentation

For example:
If someone says some science is wrong because it's "pseudoscience"
Or if someone says X doesn't exist because X is "magic," or uses any word that implies their conclusion?

So far I've thought of "begging the question" and "rhetorical tautology," and House in an episode of 'House' calls it a "faulty syllogism." Is there a concise fallacy to cite this specific kind of fallacious argument?

Comment: See [List of informal fallacies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fallacies#Informal_fallacies) for some useful examples.

Comment: That list does not have the fallacy.

Comment: Maybe [Argumentum ad lapidem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argumentum_ad_lapidem).

Comment: Appeal to the stone is to dismiss an argument out of hand because its conclusion is "absurd" or "ridiculous." It has nothing to do with calling an argument wrong because it is some word defined as wrong.

Comment: It's actually quite close to Argumentum ad lapidem.  If the act of putting X in a category of things defined to be false or absurd is thought of as "dismissing the argument," the parallels are quite strong.  It is an interesting question though, because if it has an answer, it runs the risk of being so terribly hypocritical when used.  Let's say the word for this fallacy is "flubber."  If they say "Faires don't exist because they're magic," and you reply "That argument is flubber," there's some really funny parallels between the argument and counterargument!

Comment: "Absurd" and "ridiculous" aren't defined as being wrong. That fallacy is also specific to rejecting arguments because of their absurdity. I'm looking for a fallacy that rejects an argument by defining it as wrong. "Your argument is wrong because it's a [word defined as wrong]," is equivalent to "You're wrong because you're wrong." Citing this would obviously require something much more far-reaching than appeal to the stone. As for the flubber thing, I think such a statement could be considered begging the question regardless of how obvious it might seem. You don't know fairies don't exist.

Comment: Saying that something is wrong because it is wrong, etc., is [circular reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question), Latin name is petitio principii.

Comment: As an alternate line of reasoning: what value does a named fallacy give you?  If philosophy.SE can spend hours trying to find a word that matches the exact precise meaning you want to use, what weight would it give if you were to use it in response to someone's argument? I can *fac Latina sentential* all day, but just having a nice Latin phrase doesn't mean they'll listen.

Comment: Myself, rather than quote Latin, I find it more fun to try to argue that pseudoscience can yield valid results (even if for the wrong reasons), or magic does exist (it totally does, if you define "magic" carefully).  I find it more interesting to try to open up possibilities rather than just close them down.

Comment: It would be useful in order to concisely cite why someone's argument is wrong. For instance, if someone says climate change is or isn't wrong because it's "pseudoscience," or if someone says God doesn't exist because He's a "magical" being. Both of these examples obviously invoke circular reasoning, but it's implicit in the connotation or definition of the words used to describe these things. It is exactly like saying "You're wrong because you're wrong," but it's implicit rather than explicit. To cite this, concisely, whenever anyone tries to do it would be very useful.

Comment: Petitio principii (begging the question) is *supposed* to be implicit:"*This is an informal fallacy, in which an arguer includes the conclusion to be proven within a premise of the argument, often in an indirect way such that its presence within the premise is hidden or at least not easily apparent.*" There wouldn't be a name for doing it explicitly since almost nobody does it so.

Comment: Would an answer which argues that citing a named fallacy could actually cause harm rather than help, and offers alternatives be a helpful answer?  From looking at your examples, I think there are actually multiple potential fallacies which the speaker could be making, and each one should be approached differently.  Having a citable named fallacy could encourage one to not dive into the question of which fallacy the speaker actually made, which to me seems more useful than being able to cite a name.

Answer (score 1):

sounds like begging the question to me. "X is wrong because 'X is Y'", where Y is wrong by definition, is just another way of saying 'X is wrong because X is wrong."

Answer (score 0):

To give these various labels as a refutation is to suppose that just the opposite is being claimed.  For instance, if I refute a claim or proposition or something by calling it "pseudoscience", this presupposes that it has claims to being a science.  If this is the case then the rationale is contained in the definition of pseudoscience, and the only requirement for validity is that the word fit the circumstance, e.g. astrology is a pseudoscience; whereas quantum mechanics is not pseudoscience.  Therefore, if there is any fallacy it will depend on the proposition that is being addressed which will determine if the word or label is fitting or not.